# Can the .bash_profile used to initialize a shell be recovered from a running instance?

Tags: bash

I was an idiot and accidentally overwrote my `bash_profile`. by using `>` instead of `>>`, I also don't have any backups of it which won't happen if this works.

As I still have an iTerm2 window open with the old `bash_profile` loaded and I wondered if there was a way to get a printout of it so that I can salvage it?

I have looked at recovering files and none of the options have worked and it would be great if I could get this back because it has a couple years of aliases and variables in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded"? iTerm is, well, a terminal -- it doesn't really hold files open as such. Do you mean that inside that terminal you're running a shell instance that previously *ran* that `.bash_profile`? (If so, you'll be able to dump its state, including variables and shell functions, but not to recover the original text exactly).

Comment: (BTW, the folks voting to close *are* probably right -- this isn't a question about writing code, which is StackOverflow's exclusive focus; [unix.se] is probably a better fit).

Comment: Now would be a good time to consider keeping your bash settings in a repository, [like me](https://github.com/bishopb/bashworks).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have dumped my PS1 variable but I can't remember some of the other ones and wondered if there was a way to print it out.

Comment: As in my answer, `declare -p` will dump all your shell variables -- `PS1` through `PS4` included -- in a format that can be used to redefine them without worrying about quoting &c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dump shell variables and functions, run:

```
declare -p
declare -fp
```

This will dump *all* definitions active in your session, which will include ones that were set during the execution of your `.bash_profile`.

To further dump all aliases, run:

```
alias -p
```

This should provide an adequate starting place to find data in your dotfiles that may have been lost.

<sub>Flagging community wiki to avoid gaining rep from answering a known off-topic question.</sub>

Comment: BTW, I *do* see functions present in `declare -p` output (bash 3.2.57 on MacOS), so I'm not convinced that a separate `declare -fp` invocation is needed.

Comment: Ahh -- looks like a version difference; with 4.x, I can reproduce that behavior.